# DDHotKeyCenter 'implicit conversion' warning

Tags: cocoa, xcode

Using Dave DeLong's (very) awesome DDHotKeyCenter in my app works perfectly but produces the warning 'Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'UInt32' (aka 'unsigned int')'

Would this sort of warning keep an application out of the Mac App Store? If not, in a small program such as I have been working on, is it necessary to performance to fix it? And if so, where should I begin looking?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh hey, look at that.

No, this most likely would not get your app rejected.  Regardless, it's a warning and they're there for a reason, so I fixed it:  https://github.com/davedelong/DDHotKey  The latest version simply changed the signature of a function from returning a `NSUInteger` to a `UInt32`.

Comment: Wow, you're like a ninja! Good job with that.